# Back Button in Google Chrome not retaining radio box values

Tags: html, forms, google-chrome

The back button is not retrieving radio box selections  in google chrome when submitting a form that contains all radio boxes.

See example below:

index.html

```
<form action="score.html" method="post">
<p>
Question 1: <br />
A<input name="question1" type="radio" value="A" /> <br />
B<input name="question1" type="radio" value="B" /> <br />
C<input name="question1" type="radio" value="C" /> <br />
</p>

<p>
Question 2: <br />
A<input name="question2" type="radio" value="A" /> <br />
B<input name="question2" type="radio" value="B" /> <br />
C<input name="question2" type="radio" value="C" /> <br />
</p>

<p>
Question 3: <br />
A<input name="question3" type="radio" value="A" /> <br />
B<input name="question3" type="radio" value="B" /> <br />
C<input name="question3" type="radio" value="C" /> <br />
</p>

<input name="Test" type="submit" value="Test" />
</form>
```

score.html

```
<a href="javascript:history.go(-1)>Go Back</a>
```

Here is an example of a stripped down version of a test form that I built.  When someone submits a form with all radio boxes, and then gets to the results page, I display which ones are right and which ones are wrong and give them the option to correct the wrong one.  The method of returning back is via browser back button or the history.go(-1).

In Google Chrome Only (currently running Version 35.0.1916.114 m) the radio boxes reset to blank.  In IE and Firefox they work fine.  Google chrome is our primary browser and this was at one time working with no problem.

I have also found that if you add a text box into the form and then perform the back button, all values are retained as expected.

I have also tested over HTTP / HTTPS as I had researched someone saying they had an issue with this.

My work around is to post the answers back to the previous form rather than using the history.go(-1), but we would like to get the back button going again, for those users who are prone to clicking it.

Comment: History only retains urls not user interactions.  You will probably need to retain the what radio buttons were clicked, probably in a session.  When the page renders you would need to look at what was retained and set which radio button was selected.

Comment: I have to disagree.  It works in IE and works in firefox.  It was working for the last 5+ years since its been developed and in use... and recently stopped working.  It retains text box fields, just doesnt retain the radio box fields.  Adding a text box to the form makes it work.  I've been working in website development since 1993 and I've never seen this result.

Comment: It depends on what clicking back button means. Some browsers treat it as re-submitting the previous HTTP request, which means that any information that you entered is lost. Some browsers treat it as going back to the previous browser screen, which means that any information that you entered is retained. But, I see problems in the latter case, because these browsers need to retain a lot of information stored in  JavaScript code executed not only in the last page, but also in all pages that the user can go back to.

Answer (score 1):

I got it fixed with autcomplete="off" on the checkboxes.

Found at: [Browser back button issue in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31875788/browser-back-button-issue-in-chrome)