# Browser back button issue in Chrome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, firefox

I am having a set of radio button in a form in my Rails application.

```
<input id="q_1" name="test" type="radio" value="4">
<input checked="checked" id="q_2" name="test" type="radio" value="5">
<input id="q_3" name="test" type="radio" value="4">
```

The functionality is like on clicking an unchecked radio button it redirects to the same page with the radio button clicked as `checked`.

The radio button is selected based on a `param` value in the `URL`

**Issue**:

1. Select a new radio button
2. Click on browser back button
3. Now all the a data gets refreshed based on the `param` value, except the radio button selection. The radio button is still in the initial state.

Note: The issue occurred only in `Chrome`. It's working fine in `Firefox` and `IE`

Comment: Chrome will tend, on pressing BACK, to restore the form to the state that it was when you LEFT the page, rather than when the page was initially loaded.  This might be your issue.

When the checkbox is checked, is that done as part of the page rendering, ie in rails?  Or is it done via javascript after page load?

Comment: Radio button is checked when rendering the page. Redirection after changing the selection is done via javascript. Anyway I was able to fix it by adding autocomplete="off" to the radio buttons. Thanks @MaxWilliams

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be a bug in Chrome:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=244645

I was able to fix it by adding adding `autocomplete='off'` to the radio buttons

```
<input autocomplete="off" id="q_1" name="test" type="radio" value="4">
<input autocomplete="off" checked="checked" id="q_2" name="test" type="radio" value="5">
<input autocomplete="off" id="q_3" name="test" type="radio" value="4">
```